# Core data's 'save' method creates duplicate objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to solve this issue since yesterday with no success till now. Lets say i have 5 objects in core data, each object having two fields say first_name and last_name and i have a method that takes one parameter which uniquely identifies each object. Now inside my method i change some attributes of a object, let's assume i change the first_name of a object. This is the code that follows after making the changes in order to save those changes to core data.

```
NSError *saveToContextErr;
if (![appdelegate.managedObjectContext save:&saveToContextErr])
{
    [self removeLoadingView];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"The app could not save data to device.Please contact A2OMobile Support."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

However when this is executed i have duplicate entries in my tableview that displays all the objects. So basically the older object still exists which should not happen. Can someone point out where i am going. Any help is appreciated.
The code that adds objects in core data :

```
-(void)saveToContext :(NSString *)aGuid
{    
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if(!editing)
    contact = (A2OContact *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"A2OContact" inManagedObjectContext:appdelegate.managedObjectContext];
contact.fname = fnameTextField.text;
```

This is followed by the code above to save the changes.

Comment: I think the problem is in the code you use to update the fields.. not in the save method. Check if you update the same object or you create a new instance.

Comment: @JacopoPenzo I am updating the same object which i confirmed using the unique field of the object.

Comment: can you add that code?

Comment: Okay, but before that can you please tell me if the context that is used to save the object is different from the one that is used to fetch the object can cause the issue ?

Comment: Well yes, you always have to use the same instance `appdelegate.managedObjectContext`

Comment: Ok so i checked that and i am using the same context, also i noticed that the change is getting reflected however when i refresh the page, a new copy of the updated object is created.

Comment: it would be better if you post your code to store data in coreDB. We can not set our own primary key into CoreDB. We manually have to check for the same value exist or not in DB.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel I have added the code, please check

Comment: Does the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` line get executed?  Unsurprisingly, it will insert a **new** object if it does.

Comment: see as i said this piece of code will add entry everytime you save context, you must have one field that uniquely identify your entry.

Comment: @PhillipMills- No that code is not executed in case i am trying to edit a existing object, so that's not an issue.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel- Why would that add a new object `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` is not even getting executed.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code that **does** get executed.  How do you get the object that you modify?  How do you modify it?  (Also, have you looked inside your database to see if the extra objects are really there or whether it's a tableview problem?)

Comment: To isolate this problem, I suggest you turn on sql debugging for core data and verify that there are indeed duplicate inserts.   If the number of inserts are what you expect, the issue probably is in your implementation of the NSFetchedResultsController delegate.   Check the Apple doc for this class for an example of a correct implementation.

Comment: @PhillipMills- To be honest the project i am working on is MASSIVE, i just verified that the same object is being modified using the unique id passed to the method and the object's key that i am making changes in.

Comment: @jp2g- 'sql debugging' is a new term for me, i will have to look into it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: How does the `editing` variable get set? Are you sure that it's not falling into the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` clause?  You can use breakpoints to check...

Comment: There's nothing in the code you have posted that would cause a duplicate, and there's no common situation that causes them either. If you don't post details of what happens **before** this code executes, people can only take random guesses about what the problem is.

Comment: @TomHarrington: I definitely can't post the entire code as it too lengthy, however i will try to add things related to the fetch request.